# Retrieve collection + subcollection give me an empty render

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

#### The problem

At web app startup, the main task is to retrieve all user informations that are stored in various Firestore's collections and sub-collections.

The problem is that, even if I uses promises and a Loading State to prevent an empty app rendering, the app is rendered with all collections data, except for collections that have sub-collections.

#### The process

```
- If user is logged 
-- Set Loading Status Active
-- Load Collection A
-- Load Collection B and forEach, load all sub-collection
-- Load Collection C
-- Set Loading Status Inactive
```

At this point, the app is rendered, but only with Collection A and Collection C. The collection B is loaded (I can see it by Redux Logs) but can't be seen in the app.

Those datas appears only if I change the component status (open/close a menu, for example).

#### Some code

Here's how I retrieve a collection with sub-collections:

```
export function setCompanyJobs(user) {

    return {
        type: "SET_COMPANY_JOBS",
        payload: loadCompanyJobs(user),
    };
}
```

Function that retrieve the main collection

```
export function loadCompanyJobs(user) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let companyJobs = [];

        db.collection("company").doc(user.selectedCompany).collection("jobs").get().then((jobs) => {


            jobs.forEach((job) => {

                loadJobLinkedServices(user, job).then((jobLinkedServices) => {

                    companyJobs.push({
                        id:     job.id,
                        ...

                    });
                });

            });

            resolve(companyJobs);

        }).catch(function (error) {

            ...
        });
    });
}
```

Function that retrieve all collection's sub-collections

```
export function loadJobLinkedServices(user, job){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let jobLinkedServices = [];
        db.collection("company").doc(user.selectedCompany).collection("jobs").doc(job.id).collection("linkedServices").get().then((linkedServices) => {

            linkedServices.forEach((linkedService) => {

                jobLinkedServices.push({

                    id:         linkedService.id,
                    ...
                });

            });

            resolve(jobLinkedServices)

        }).catch(function (error) {

            ...
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let companyJobs = [];

    db.collection("company").doc(user.selectedCompany).collection("jobs").get().then((jobs) => {


        jobs.forEach((job) => {

            loadJobLinkedServices(user, job).then((jobLinkedServices) => {

                companyJobs.push({
                    id:     job.id,
                    ...

                });
            });

        });

        resolve(companyJobs);

    }).catch(function (error) {

        ...
    });
});
```

nothing ensure that your Promise resolves only after ALL the queries triggered in the `jobs.forEach()` loop are done (i.e. the promises returned by the calls to the `loadJobLinkedServices` function have resolved).

I don't know reactjs but I think you can use the JavaScript [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method along the following lines:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


    let promises = [];

    let companyJobs = [];

    db.collection("company").doc(user.selectedCompany).collection("jobs").get().then((jobs) => {


        jobs.forEach((job) => {

            promises.push(loadJobLinkedServices(user, job));

        });

        Promise.all(promises).
        then(results => {
          //Loop over the results array to populate the companyJobs array
           resolve(companyJobs);
        })

    }).catch(function (error) {

        ...
    });
});
```

---

Also, don't forget to correctly chain your calls to the different asynchronous functions, i.e. something like:

```
query Collection A
THEN query Collection B
THEN query all sub-collections (with Promise.all())
THEN query Collection C
THEN set Loading Status Inactive
```

---

Finally, a last remark: Note that the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) method returns a promise, so I am not sure that you need to wrap the calls to the `get()` method into some new `Promises` (Again, I am not versed in reactjs, so this remark may be wrong).

In other words, I think you could do something like the following (for example for the `loadJobLinkedServices` function):

```
export function loadJobLinkedServices(user, job){

         let jobLinkedServices = [];
         return db.collection("company").doc(user.selectedCompany).collection("jobs").doc(job.id).collection("linkedServices").get()
        .then((linkedServices) => {

            linkedServices.forEach((linkedService) => {

                jobLinkedServices.push({

                    id:         linkedService.id,
                    ...
                });

            });

            return jobLinkedServices;

        }).catch(function (error) {

            ...
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the first solution. The problem was that!
Thank you also for the chaining suggestion. I had already done it with a PromiseAll. 
Also, thank you for the last suggestion, I will try it